# Corrections in Perturbation theory

Tags: quantum-mechanics, perturbation-theory

Is there a way to construct a bound on the perturbative corrections to a problem in perturbation theory? For example, if I have the standard 1st order correction to the eigensolutions of a problem 
\begin{equation}|n\rangle= |n^{(0)}\rangle + \sum_{k\neq n} |k^{(0)}\rangle\frac{V_{nk}}{E^{(0)}_{k}-E^{(0)}_{n}}+\ldots\end{equation}
Is there a way to determine the size of the first order correction to ensure the resulting perturbation isn't "too big"?

Comment: Many results on the convergence of perturbation series can be found in T. Kato "Perturbation Theory of Linear Operators".